# Como vuelvo a un hash tree en git?

Tags: git

Borre todos mis cambios locales de mi repositorio local por que hice hard reset a un head diferente y no hice backup, entonces investigando vi que puedo listar todos los cambios perdidos con `git fsck --lost-found` alli encontre el que al parecer pueden ser mis archivos antes del cambio y queria volver a ellos con `git reset --hard a7df355af9ed4ea3260a975c40681a348fa605f1` pero me sale el siguiente error:

**error: object a7df355af9ed4ea3260a975c40681a348fa605f1 is a tree, not a commit**

**fatal: Could not parse object 'a7df355af9ed4ea3260a975c40681a348fa605f1'**

Como podria volver a ese hash tree?

Comment: Revisa la salida de `git read-tree -n a7df355af9ed4ea3260a975c40681a348fa605f1 `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer un restore para ponerlo en tu árbol de trabajo o en el index, según prefieras:

```
git restore --worktree --staged --source el-tree-id -- .
```

`--staged` es para ponerlo también en el index.

Esto es un hack en toda regla... en realidad no estás trabajando con la historia (como buscar el commit que apunta al árbol) pero si es lo que necesitas, pues espero que sea suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Aplica

```
git reflog
```

Te listará todos los cambios de rama que has hecho últimamente. Por ejemplo

```
asfggh  - reset hard asdggh
errtyu  - moving from master to develop
aaX134  - merge release/123 on top of master
```

Ahí examinando lo que te diga tendrías que volver a `errtyu`  que sería la última vez que estuviste en develop antes de sustituirlo con tu reset hard